# Where to put the try statement in python

Tags: python, try-catch

1I'm learning python and finding it difficult to undestand where to place the try and except statement

```
def divide (n1, n2):
    try:
        d = n1/n2
    except :
        print("Wrong")
```

Then divide (10,0) produces the correct "Wrong"

However if i put the try at the top of the function, it doesn't work

```
try:
    def divide (n1, n2):
        d = n1/n2
except :
        print("Wrong")
```

Then divide(10,0) produces the regular traceback error.

Why doesn't the except work in the second example?

Comment: You put it exactly where the code in the `try` portion would be if you *weren't* guarding it with `try`.  You don't even have to think about it, it's always completely obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is the right way to use it.

In the second one, you are defining the function:

```
    def divide (n1, n2):
        d = n1/n2
```

So, when you call it, the try statement is not even executed. The try and except statements are outside the scope, and just useless in the way you want to use them. In this example, the "Wrong" output would be printed just if, when reaching the try, the devide function could not be defined, which is not the case

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html) you will find the documentation of how to handle errors and exceptions in Python.

Answer (score 2):

It's because if you don't run the function in the try-except section, it always goes through, since a function will always work without being called, if you call it inside the try-except, it will work:

```
try:
    def divide (n1, n2):
        d = n1/n2
    print(divide(0,0))
except :
    print("Wrong")
```

It will give:

```
Wrong
```

But of all solutions, you #1 solution is the best.

Comment: @Schang Ugh, not me, anyways, it's okay

Answer (score 1):

Your second try-catch only includes how you *define* the function, and your `def` has no exception to raise. And if you call this somewhere: `divide(10, 0)`, it's already outside of try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

As the function definition is in the try... except block and not the function call. And always the function definition will not get executed unless it's called (function call should always be in try...except). Hence the second code you mentioned is not efficient enough to catch the exception.

Below piece of code would also work :

```
def divide (n1, n2):
    d = n1/n2

try:
    divide(12, 0)
except:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Oh that's nicely explained

Answer (score 0):

in python Try Except  will be execute or run if what your execute result error. which is in your example 2 you use **def**(fucntion) and **def** in python will not be execute before there call, so that why the except don't work